# Can I use Watir to scrape data from a website on a linux server without monitor?

Tags: linux, watir, web-scraping

Can I use Watir to scrape data from a website (AJAX used) but on a linux server without monitor? (linode.com) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), either [Celerity](http://github.com/jarib/celerity) or [watir-webdriver](http://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver) (through the [remote Selenium2/WebDriver server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar)).
2. Use a real browser + a virtual X server (Xvfb). I'd recommend using [watir-webdriver](http://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver)'s Firefox driver and the [Headless](http://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem for a simple way to control this from Ruby.

This is basically a tradeoff between speed and realism. Personally I'd go with #2 if the site has any complex JavaScript or invalid HTML, but both approaches could be worth investigation.

For the future, I'm keeping an eye on [this project](http://code.google.com/p/webkitdriver/), which looks like a terrific idea.

Comment: wow, that looks gooooood. Seems to me that I am going to do lots of reading over the weekend :-)