# How do I run Firefox browser headless with my Ruby script?

Tags: firefox, watir, firewatir, watir-webdriver, headless-browser

I need to be able to run my Ruby scripts with my Hudson builds but don't want a browser window attempting to open.
I tried:

```
batman:ETW cmiller$ ./createAccount.rb -b
```

but this did not work.

How can I run my Ruby scripts using FireWatir headless?

Running on Mac OSX

Comment: Telling us your command-line doesn't show us anything useful without the actual source code being run.

Comment: The source code is not what is pertinent here though, the command line is showing me running -b which works in watir to run the browser headless but does not work in firewatir.

Comment: removed ruby in favor of watir-webdriver in the tags.  You don't mention what OS the CI is running on, which might be a factor in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at using Watir-Webdriver instead of just plain Watir or Fire-watir.   Especially since the only way to work with newer versions of firefox is going to be via Watir-Webdriver.

There's an earlier SO question where the answer covers just this sort of thing, so I'd suggest trying what is described there there first.   [Can I use Watir to scrape data from a website on a linux server without monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861871/can-i-use-watir-to-scrape-data-from-a-website-on-a-linux-server-without-monitor/3863321#3863321)

Also since I now know you are using Mac OS, the advice in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/c7ac3c2e45919587) from the webdriver google group might be more applicable to you

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest the usage of PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
Add binaries to your path and run:

```
    MEDBEDbs-iMac:~ medbedb$ irb
    1.9.3p392 :001 > require 'watir-webdriver'
     => true 
    1.9.3p392 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
     => #<Watir::Browser:0x..fe670a70a449fe1ca url="about:blank" title=""> 
    1.9.3p392 :003 > b.goto "www.google.com"
     => "http://www.google.md/" 
    1.9.3p392 :004 > b.url 
     => "http://www.google.md/" 
    1.9.3p392 :005 > b.title
     => "Google"
    1.9.3p392 :007 > b.text
 => "+Вы\nПоиск\nКартинки\nКарты\nPlay\nПочта\nДиск\nКалендарь\nЕщё\nВойти\n×\nОткрывай любимые сайты быстрее\nЗагрузить Google Chrome\n\nМолдoва\n\n \nРасширенный поиск\nЯзыковые инструменты\n\nGoogle.md предлагается на: Moldovenească\n\nРекламные программыВсё о GoogleGoogle.com\n© 2013 - Правила и принципы"
```

Comment: How do I turn off the logging information for phantom js, i.e INFO, WARNING etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://watirmelon.com/tag/headless/. 
I have followed http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/ on Linux that works for me. In above link the tutorial is intended for Mac

Here is extract of the links, how to use headless browser:

```
  require 'watir-webdriver' 
    require 'headless'
```

Now start headless and browser

```
   headless = Headless.new
    headless.start 
    b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com' puts b.title
    b.close headless.destroy
```

Your browser should run headless.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the key content of these links? (In case they stop working in the future)

Comment: Headless is NOT going to work in windows. Use phantomjs instead.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is opening the window as part of its normal operation and behavior.

You could look into using [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), which supplies the ability to navigate a site. It isn't a browser, but uses Nokogiri underneath to let you grab DOM information and manipulate forms, submit them, and retrieve any resulting page changes. Mechanize doesn't support parsing/executing Javascript though, which puts you back into WATIR's realm.